# Timeout when vagrant up (waiting machine to boot)

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I am trying to create a new vagrant on mac, by calling `vagrant up --provider virtual box`
The virtual box version I am using is 4.3.30 (also tried 4.3.22, 4.3.34 and 5.something).
My Vagrantfile contains:

```
config.vm.box_download_insecure = true
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 4443
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000
config.vm.boot_timeout = 500
config.vm.box_check_update = false
```

We didn't set a username, the default username is vagrant. It tries to use private key for auth. It stuck at:

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

Anyone could give me some suggestion on why is this? I tried to specify  private key in the config file, but seems not working either.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/debugging.html

Comment: @hek2mgl thank you, I tried to set the logging to debug level, but didn't see error obvious :(

Comment: Which private key are you using?

Comment: The private key on my mac under ~/.ssh @hek2mgl

Comment: That's the wrong key. You need to use the `insecure_private_key` from Vagrant. Google for that term. Basically vagrant up would use that key by default.